# jStorage doesn't work in IE runned by Selenium

Tags: jquery, selenium, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, jstorage

I use jStorage to synchronize tabs in IE. When I try to test it with Selenium WebDriver, it does not work.

So, this lines

```
$.jStorage.subscribe('test', function () {alert('test');}); 
$.jStorage.publish('test')
```

does work in manually runned IE and in Selenium's IE in one tab.

And does not work in different tabs in Selenium's IE.

Comment: I don't think it would work unless you injected the jStorage.js  into the WebDriver by executing it with a JavascriptExecutor.

Comment: This script is not executing by JavascriptExecutor, it is a component of the web page.